# Pass two same parameters in graphql

Tags: graphql, ransack, graphiql

In `GraphiQL`, how to pass two same parameter using `ransack`? I want to get data where status not equal to "A" and "B"

```
 {
      invoice(
        q: {id_eq: 7, status_not_eq: "A",status_not_eq:"B"}
      ) {
        status
        paymentStatus
      }
    }
```

**Error**

```
"There can be only one input field named \"status_not_eq\""
```

Comment: Can you share your schema.graphqls or at least the part for this query?

Comment: I can't show you because the code written by the backend team. If I remove one of the `status_not_eq`, it works. But I want to have both .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, and considering what you have experienced yourself when querying the service with only one `status_not_eq`; and not being able to confirm it with the actual GraphQL contract, I conclude that this query admits only one `status_not_eq` per request.

If you want to query with a different criteria (in this case, admitting an array of `status_not_eq`), the contract would need to change and the implementation would have to be coded (in case it doesn't exist).

Today, somewhere in the schema for this query it says:

```
...
tenancy_id_eq:Int, status_not_eq:String
...
```

What you need to ask the backend team:

```
...
tenancy_id_eq:Int, status_not_eq:[String]
...
```

Comment: thanks for the hint ! Will update once I get the reply from them.